# Kafka - Re-process messages in topics

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have a Kafka cluster. At this moment just for testing, there is only one topic and to this topic, 1 consumer is taking the same messages from the topic and processing, and storing them on the database. But, if I have any problem storing on the database and throw an exception, for example, a `PersistenceException`, then the message flow is interrupted. How can I handle it?

How do we re-process data when something goes wrong?
Can we re-process messages in topics?

Did anyone face this scenario?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messages are durable in Kafka for at least 7 days, by default.

Within that period, Kafka consumer group offsets can be reset or rewound using `kafka-consumer-groups` CLI, for example

Otherwise, restart your consumer code, and the last message offset that wasn't committed will be reprocessed

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so there are several bits here:

1. Topic persistence:

A topic is stored as a set of log segment files. The size of the segment is controlled by `segment.bytes` property (1gb default). When Kafka writes a new segment, it either compacts or deletes old files.
The behavior is controlled by the following topic configuration properties:

- cleanup.policy - "compact" or "delete", default - delete

  - compact - keep the latest message for a given message key when the log compaction is performed
  - delete - just delete segments where the messages are too od.
- retention.bytes - how big a topic can grow before Kafka deletes or compacts old log segments (default unlimited)
- retention.ms - how long Kafka keeps the log segments for (default 7 days)

Notice, if you do not have more than 1 segment, nothing is going to be deleted or compacted.

2. Consumer

There are following ways to manage offsets in Kafka:

- autocommit (default) - client commits in `Consume()` call every `auto.commit.interval.ms` milliseconds (5 seconds default)
- manual via CommitOffsets().
- in kafka transaction via SendOffsetsToTransaction() - when in addition to db processing we send some messages.

Conclusion:

- set up topic persistence for the purpose (e.g. to rebuild the database from the topic you would need `compact` policy)
- database updates should be idempotent or committed using a transaction manager that ties database and Kafka transactions. A database might record processed messages identifiers (either topic/partition/offset or a record's guid) to avoid double processing.
- If the consumer crashes, it will start where it left off (last committed offset). Just note that:

  - Do not call Consume() until commit succeeds in the auto commit case
  - Do not commit offsets until transaction succeeds for manual commit
  - Use transaction manager and SendOffsetsToTransaction() in kafka transaction.
    In the first two cases, since we commit offsets after db commit() we might replay the last batch, hence idempotency is very important as we will get duplicates =)

Comment: so what if i dont want to set the autoCommit so if my consumer has failed processing a message, it would again retry after sometime and until that moment, the message would be staying in the queue? I am kinda getting confused between ```EnableAutoCommit``` and ```AutoCommitIntervalInMs``` . can you please help?

Comment: Consumer offsets are only relevant if you re-create consumer or your application exits. If you keep calling Consume() without committing offsets you get the next message in the topic regardless of the processing result. So, an example - message 1 -> start (db, kafka) tx -> do some processing -> failure -> SendOffsetsToTx() -> rollback. If you crash here, consumer will restart with message 1. if you call consume() again - you will get message 2.